# Were bakers supposed to receive any rewards for voting?

Tags: voting

I am just curious if any rewards at all were planned for bakers who actually voted?
Bakers represent the voters, you can compare them to similar model used in US election. Voters are not voting directly like in some countries, where you can go and make your choice directly. Instead, in US, voters are delegating their voting power to delegates. Very similar to Tezos voting mechanism. As far as I know, delegates are not doing their work for free in US election campaigns. So are there any incentives for Tezos delegates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegates are compensated by the people who let them vote on their behalf. You can consider this compensation is included in the baker’s fees.

Comment: Sure, I would not mind to assume that logic as correct and would never asked this question, but we have a special reward for accusing double baking. Why it is so? Why double baking is treated differently? These two activities are considered to be related to network health. Preventing double baking is network health activity on micro level, while Voting is macro health related network activity to avoid forks. As for me Voting is even more important

Comment: @indigo voting is important but not voting does not break the integrity of the chain. The worst case of not voting is things just stay as they are but the worst case of double baking is destabilizing the consensus if not handled properly. Surely you will appreciate the difference in nature.

Comment: I thought that not voting can potentially lead to hard fork or not being able to make an important decision, if quorum was not met. Isn't it?

Comment: @indigo this is incorrect. Not voting does not lead to hardfork. The quorum will just reduce for next voting period

Comment: this is interesting information. I never heard about easing  quorum requirements. Currently it is 80%, it is quite high. I am not even sure it will be reached this time. Is there information about new quorum level? Thanks

Comment: @indigo 80% has been reached in this first proposal period when it is not even required for more details check this https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/357